# OpenModelica OMOptim does not start omc

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

I am trying to use OMOptim within OpenModelica. When starting OMOptim, it took it a considerable amount of time to put the canvas on; once it was on, I looked in the Message Output (under Log/MO) and found the message OMC not started.  Please start it again (menu OMC->restart). I try Tools/OMC/start omc and just like the previous post, I get:

```
08:43:31] OMC not started. Please start it again (menu OMC->restart) 
[08:57:34] OMC: unable to find OMC server, Object reference file C:/Users/Daniel/AppData/Local/Temp/OpenModelica/OMOptim//openmodelica.objid.OMOptim{E5F24F12-CB25-40B3-81BD-255279DBC379}085713394 not created.
```

Of course trying to load a model into OMOptim fails with complaint that omc is not running.

Comment: I thought we fixed this but it seems not. I will have a look and see what I can do.

Comment: Thank you for your effort.  BTW, I am running OpenModelica / OMOptim under Windows 7 64bit; don't know if this is relevant.